# Generate all possible combinations of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I'm trying to print all combinations of two strings.

```
attributes = "old green".split()
persons = "car bike".split()
```

What I expect:

```
old car
old bike
green car
green bike
```

What I have tried so far:

```
from itertools import product

attributes = "old green".split()
persons = "car bike".split() 

print([list(zip(attributes, p)) for p in product(persons,repeat=1)])
```

Comment: What do you consider to be inputs in this example? Words? Delimited by only spaces? What forms can the input take? Be _specific_. And tell us, what is wrong with your attempt? What problem did you encounter? What did you try to fix it? What documentation did you read?

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass `persons` **and** `attributes` to `product`:

```
>>> [p for p in product(attributes, persons)]
[('old', 'car'), ('old', 'bike'), ('green', 'car'), ('green', 'bike')]
```

and then concatenate these strings:

```
>>> [' '.join(p) for p in product(attributes, persons)]
['old car', 'old bike', 'green car', 'green bike']
```

In case you want to print them individually you can use a `for`-loop instead of the list comprehension:

```
for p in product(attributes, persons):
    print(' '.join(p))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a list comprehension. This works if this is the end of the exercise. If you are hoping at some point to add another list of words then you will need a different method.

```
[elem + ' ' + elem2 for elem in attributes for elem2 in persons]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use two for loops like:

```
attributes = ['old', 'green']
persons = ['car', 'bike']
for x in attributes:
    for y in persons:
        print x, y
```

output:

```
old car
old bike
green car
green bike
```